# Dehumidifier Does not work and reports incorrect humidity

Tags: dehumidifier

I've looked through a bunch of other DIY sites and the questions on here but couldn't find the exact issue I'm facing. I have a dehumidifier in my basement that is set to run continuously and drain through the hose attachment into our sump pit. The humidity meter on it reports 40 or so once it's been going, but it is humid as an August afternoon down there. Has to be at least 80% or more. It used to work great when it was first plugged in but now not so much.  Something is really odd because occasionally it will shut off because the tank is full (even though the aforementioned hose is connected). This takes a while though - under normal use without the hose it would full up every day - now it takes weeks for that to happen. None of the symptoms I was told to look for, condenser coils aren't frosted or anything, air filter is clean.  I'm wondering if it's something that could be fixed. Thanks for your help.

-Jayce

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like the humidifier needs service, and thus is off-topic

Comment: So just to clarify is fixing your own appliances not considered diy?

Comment: Not that I know of. Repairs tend to be specific to models and we can't offer specific repair advice

Comment: @jayce, check out the ["on-topic" guidance in the help section](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):  "questions regarding small appliances" are off-topic.  The site is focused on home improvements, which refers to "the parts of your home that are typically included when you buy or sell it" (the structure and infrastructure, the kinds of major appliances that normally convey with it, but not the operation of those, and the tools and materials used for home improvement).

Answer (score 1):

If the dehumidifier is working and producing water, I would look for other sources of water or moisture entering the space. To gauge how well the dehumidifier is working, calculate how much humidity (water) the unit removes in a given period of time and compare this figure to the specifications or capacity of the unit. Your comparisons won't be exact but you can be close. If the dehumidifier seems to be performing as it should, look elsewhere for a source of excess humidity. As far as the reading on the dehumidifier itself, I would not rely too much on it being accurate. I would buy another gauge and compare the 2 numbers. If you really need an accurate figure there are devices called sling psychrometers you can buy that will give you an exact reading reading. To consider sizing of a dehumidifier, I have 4000 sq. ft. of finished and conditioned space, and have a 70 pint rated dehumidifier that runs about 18 hours a day to keep the humidity below 45%.

Comment: So that's the thing, nothing's really changed down there. It used to work better but I am at a loss as to explain why it suddenly doesn't dehumidify. Again it used to work well (gauge seemed to actually mean something) but I can't seem to find my exact symptoms anywhere.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: One more thing I can say; the dehumidifiers made in recent years only seem to last a couple years. I do not know if it is because they are made in a foreign country or if the mfg. standards are so relaxed. I now buy  them with a cheap insurance policy that has paid for itself many times.